# Comparing 2 arrays via user input in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, input

I've got 2 arrays of the same length.  One is a string of colors and the other is a float of sizes.  I want the user to be able to select the color and then cycle through the sizes array for the larges size of the corresponding color.  I've been able to cycle through the lists and display all of the colors with the matching size but I can't seem to figure out how to do it just by the user selecting the color.  Arrays are as follows:

```
string[] colors = new string[] { "red", "blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "green", "blue", "yellow", "red", "green", "yellow", "blue" };
float[] size = new float[] { 12.6f, 2.8f, 19.3f, 28.9f, 30f, 6.2f, 15.5f, 22.1f, 16f, 9.2f, 10.5f, 3.5f };
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What UI framework are you using?  Can you show what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two arrays switch to a single array of a custom object.

```
public class MyColor{
     public MyColor(string color, float maxSize){
          Color = color;
          MaxSize = maxsize;
     }

     public string Color { get; }
     public float MaxSize { get; }
}
```

Your array would then be:

```
MyColor[] colors = new MyColor[] {
    new MyColor("red", 12.6f),
    // etc.
}
```

In your view you'd then use the SelectedItem to show the maximum size.